# Changing position of the submenu caret

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I have namely simple modification to do but with no luck.

On this page http://www.skylinemotorcars.com/ there is submenu (inside Search Vehicles) with those caret buttons.
What I would like to do is to move those carets next to the word, for example : by Make> or by Price> instead of leaving them aligned right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a style on link tags that uses the :after pseudo selector that inserts the arrow, from bootstrap.css:

```
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  ...
  margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Edit the margin right property to get the arrow closer universally. You'll have to further edit the markup if you want the arrows to be closer depending on the text width.